# Directive to add comment

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, comments

I find a bit too long the way to comment code on HTML `<!-- My comment -->`, 7 characters when in other languages you can do the same with 2.

I'm new to AngularJS and saw this prase somewhere while reading some articles *"teaching HTML new tricks"*, would it be possible to write a directive to shorten the way of making comments in HTML?

Maybe something like:

```
<c My comment>
```

I know that there are cons like the format of the comment breaking some rules, or not having the IDE shortcuts, but still I ask, to see how to do such a thing (and learn new tricks) or to know why it is not possible.

**UPDATE 1**: Thanks to the ideas proposed on the answers by @denisazevedo and @Todd I found a way of making it work as described previously, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ze3k5gaw/3/). Now, can you see some issues here that I couldn't find during this brief testing? (would it be better to ask another question?)

**UPDATE 2**: The previus fiddle doesn't works properly, if the the comment ends with  `c` the letter is not included (`>` is not displayed at the output either), and on IE shows the comment backwards.

Comment: tryed code that doesn't even compile

Comment: Show the directive you tried. Or better, create a _fiddle_ or a _plunkr_. It would be easier to help you, instead of doing all the work.

Comment: can't see the value of a fiddle with broken HTML, or the empty "skeleton" of a directive, I know that a fiddle helps (I've asked for it several times), but in this case I think is useless

Comment: I posted an answer for this, not sure if it'll work for you.

Comment: dude, based on your solution... you should def mark my answer as correct, since it's essentially just a variation... I want to increase my meaningless rep on SO. @FelipeP

Comment: I wouldn't have a problem to accept it, but my variation has some issues, don't know if you want to update your question to include this buggy variation (read my las comments on the other answer)

Answer (score 1):

### WRONG:

**My suggestion: Try using a new text editor.**

What are you using? Notepad?

I prefer sublime text, but there are other free text editors, and they all generally use **`CTRL`**+**`/`**. Even codepen.io implements this. just highlight and hotkey!

### RIGHT

### EDIT II:

**Now supports multiple comment attributes**

This now takes the attributes as hyphen separated "statement attributes", replaces the hyphens with spaces, and inserts a comment containing the formatted text for each "statement attribute".

codepen here: http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/0a1b5a595e8dd3db7e74b84a1dbc1c72

```
// js
myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);

myapp.directive('c', function() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function(element) {
        var comments  = [],
            attrs = element[0].attributes;
        for (var i = 0, j = attrs.length; i < j; i++) {
          var f = element[0].attributes[i].name.replace('-', ' ');
          comments.push(document.createComment(f));
        }

        element.replaceWith(comments);
      }
    };

    return directive;
});
```

and then...

```
<!-- Original HTML -->
<div ng-app='myapp'>
  <c this-is-a-comment-element and-so-is-this>
</div>
```

and magically this is rendered:

```
<div ng-app='myapp'>
    <!-- this is a comment element -->
    <!-- and so is this -->
</div>
```

Comment: @FelipeP, I did... I can't get your fiddle to display the intended comment in dev tools. Do you have another that has your update?

Comment: just have that fiddle, I can see the comment (chrome 38.0.2125.111)

Comment: well, that works in IE also, but I would like to keep writing comments without having to hit `-` instead of the spacebar :)

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I would use the features of a good editor, but if you really want a directive for this, the best that comes to my mind is:

```
.directive('c', function() {  
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            text: '@t'
        },
        template: '<!-- {{text}} -->'
    };
});
```

And how to use it:

```
<c t="My comment">
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/denisazevedo/qvoy2c7r/)

Comment: Thanks, that is a valid way of doing it, in my example I was trying to avoid using an attribute to define the comment, and there is where my concerns are. Also, it would be desirable if the directive dissapear and only the comment is present (I guess there is a "replace" option for that), but there you may get the "exactly one root element" error.

Comment: Now that I inspect the fiddle more carefully, I see that the comment part of the template isn't evaluated properly

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what the issue is. I would post a new question for this to keep simple to follow. Thanks

Comment: was thinking about issues over different browsers, comments and stuff like that, in chrome looks like it works, but in IE the comment is displayed backwards, that kind of things

Comment: But I think this kind of thing is a browser matter, I don't know if it is possible for us to force how the browser will interpret a comment in the DOM :(

Comment: I heard that there is a thing called a "hack" that you use when browsers have they own interpretation of a standad :)